# How to rank a column within a group ordered by a date column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following sample data:

```
car_id  owner_id    service_date
1        user2  2016-01-02 00:00:00
1        user2  2016-03-02 00:00:00
1        user3  2016-11-02 00:00:00
1        user4  2017-01-02 00:00:00
1        user4  2017-02-12 00:00:00
1        user1  2017-03-22 00:00:00
1        user2  2017-03-24 00:00:00
```

I am trying to rank `owner_id` column for a given `car_id` in `sql-server`.

For a given `car_id` value, the rank column should increase by one, if the 'owner_id' value is different from the 'owner_id' value in the previous row, where rows are sorted by `service_date` in ascending order.

Expected Output:

```
car_id  owner_id    service_date    rnk
1        user2  2016-01-02 00:00:00 1
1        user2  2016-03-02 00:00:00 1
1        user3  2016-11-02 00:00:00 2
1        user4  2017-01-02 00:00:00 3
1        user4  2017-02-12 00:00:00 3
1        user1  2017-03-22 00:00:00 4
1        user2  2017-03-24 00:00:00 5
```

I tried to find the rank with `dense_rank()` function by partitioning over the car_id and owner_id. But it lead to wrong ranks.

```sql
CREATE TABLE #tb_example (
    car_id INT,
    owner_id NVARCHAR(5),
    service_date SMALLDATETIME
);

INSERT INTO #tb_example (car_id, owner_id, service_date) VALUES (1, 'user2', '2016-01-02');
INSERT INTO #tb_example (car_id, owner_id, service_date) VALUES (1, 'user2', '2016-03-02');
INSERT INTO #tb_example (car_id, owner_id, service_date) VALUES (1, 'user3', '2016-11-02');
INSERT INTO #tb_example (car_id, owner_id, service_date) VALUES (1, 'user4', '2017-01-02');
INSERT INTO #tb_example (car_id, owner_id, service_date) VALUES (1, 'user4', '2017-02-12');
INSERT INTO #tb_example (car_id, owner_id, service_date) VALUES (1, 'user1', '2017-03-22');
INSERT INTO #tb_example (car_id, owner_id, service_date) VALUES (1, 'user2', '2017-03-24');

SELECT *, 
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY car_id, owner_id ORDER BY service_date) AS rnk 
FROM #tb_example
ORDER BY service_date;
```

Comment: You didn't use `DENSE_RANK`, you used `RANK`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT *,           
            CASE 
              WHEN owner_id <> COALESCE(LAG(owner_id) OVER 
                                  (PARTITION BY car_id ORDER BY service_date), owner_id) 
                     THEN 1
              ELSE 0 
            END AS grp
    FROM #tb_example
)
SELECT *,
       SUM(grp) OVER (PARTITION BY car_id ORDER BY service_date) + 1 AS rnk
FROM cte 
ORDER BY service_date;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1e86d97dddf5f0dfde94af88686acf19)

The query uses `LAG` to detect changes in `owner_id` within the same `car_id` partition, with order defined by `servic_date`.

Using `grp` field we use `SUM(grp) OVER ..` to compute rank as a running total of changes.